# Javascript not firing on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form that should fire JS on submit but it is not working. I have looked for syntax errors or any mismatches between the JS and the form but I haven't found anything. I have been trying to fix this all day and I would really appreciate it an extra pair of eyes on this. Thanks a lot for looking

This is my HTML form:

```
<div style="margin-top: 1rem">
    <div
      id="wpcf7-f2066-p2006-o2"
      class="wpcf7"
      dir="ltr"
      lang="en-US"
      role="form"
    >
      <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
      <form
        class="download-form"
        method="POST"
        id="download-form"
      >
        <p style="padding-bottom: 30px">
          <label for="platform" style="color:white;">Select Platform:</label>
          <select id="Platform__C" name="Platform">
            <option value="ovf">VMware/Oracle Virtual Box (ovf)</option>
            <option value="xva">Citrix Xenserver (xva)</option>
            <option value="vhd">Microsoft HyperV (vhd)</option>
            <option value="qcow2">Xen/OpenStack/KVM (qcow2)</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <div style="display: table-caption;">
          <label style="color:white;">
            First Name
            <span class="f-name">
              <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required="" />
            </span>
          </label>
            <label>
              Last Name
              <span class="l-name">
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required="" />
              </span>
            </label>
            <label>
              Company
              <span class="company">
                   <input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" required="" />
              </span>
            </label>
            <label>
              Business Address
              <span class="email-618">
                   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Business Email" required="" />
              </span>
              <div id="dialog" visibility="hidden"></div>
            </label>
            
            <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea
            id="message"
            name="message"
            placeholder="Message"
            required=""
    ></textarea>

          
        </div>
        <div class="update_terms" style="color:white;">
          <label>
            <input
              id="f_term_condition"
              class="update_term_condition"
              name="acceptance-263"
              type="checkbox"
              value="1"
              aria-invalid="false"
            /><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label"
              >I agree to <a href="https://device42.com/eula/">EULA</a> and
              <a href="https://device42.com/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a></span
            >
          </label>
        </div>


<!--    Following must be set carefully for form type/name-->
    <input type="hidden" id="Download_Form" name="Download_Form__c" value="Download">
<!--Leave following untouched. These are filled by GAConnector integration-->
    <input type="hidden" id="fc_campaign" name="gaconnector__First_Click_Campaign__c">
    <input id="fc_channel" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Channel__c" style="display: none">
    <input  id="fc_content" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Content__c" style="display: none">
    <input  id="fc_landing" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Landing_Page__c" style="display: none">
    <input  id="fc_medium" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Medium__c" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" id="fc_referrer" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Referrer__c">
    <input  id="fc_source" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Source__c" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" id="fc_term" name ="gaconnector__First_Click_Term__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_campaign" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Campaign__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_channel" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Channel__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_content" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Content__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_landing" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Landing_Page__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_medium" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Medium__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_referrer" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Referrer__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_source" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Source__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="lc_term" name ="gaconnector__Last_Click_Term__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="OS" name ="gaconnector__Operating_System__c">
    <input id="GA_Client_ID" name ="gaconnector__Google_Analytics_Client_ID__c" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" id="gclid" name ="gaconnector__GCLID__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="browser" name ="gaconnector__Browser__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="city" name ="gaconnector__City__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="country" name ="gaconnector__Country__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="device" name ="gaconnector__Device__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="time_zone" name ="gaconnector__Time_Zone__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="latitude" name ="gaconnector__Latitude_from_IP__c">
    <input type="hidden" id="longitude" name ="gaconnector__Longitude__c">
  
    <div class="send-button">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" style="background-color:#F37033; padding:10px 20px 10px 20px; color: white; margin-top:20px;">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the JS that should be firing:

```
 <!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
    function convertFormToJSON(form) {
        const array = $(form).serializeArray(); // Encodes the set of form elements as an array of names and values.
        const json = {};
        $.each(array, function () {
            //console.log(this.name);
            json[this.name] = this.value || "";
        });
        return json;
    }
    $("#download-form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = $(e.target);
        var jsond = convertFormToJSON(form);
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('6Lcwyh4gAAAAADLf0CVv04A7IGftq8_zxWuFirnO', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
                // Add your logic to submit to your backend server here.
                jsond["recaptcha_token__c"] = token;
                //console.log(jsond);
                const jsondstring = JSON.stringify(jsond);
                //console.log(jsondstring);``
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "https://3dvchn7hw6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/submit",
                    //url : "http://localhost:8090/hello",
                    dataType: "json",
                    crossDomain: "true",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: jsondstring,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json" // this shows the expected content type
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // clear form and show a success message
                        alert("Successful "+ data.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("download-form").reset();
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        // show an error message
                        alert("UnSuccessful "+ data.responseText);
                        $("dialog").css('visibility','visible');
                        $("#dialog").html("Please use a Business Email address or double check for any typos");
                    }});
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tested your code and the form onsubmit worked. Are there any errors in your devtools?

Comment: Hi @Deor there should be a "Successful" message when the form is submitted but nothing is happening.

Comment: What errors are in your console? Where do you define `grecaptcha`?

Comment: The issue is not with the event triggering. Add an alert right when the event gets called and you will see it is being triggered. The issue is most likely stemming from your grecaptcha code. grecaptcha is probably not readying properly.

Comment: Remove the line `e.preventDefault();` and try submitting. Does that now work? Its usually used to prevent e.g a form submitting or on links to stop it going to a url

Comment: @j08691 I am getting the following error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function" and it highlights this part of the script ".on("submit", function (e) {v"

Comment: Hi @Nick, I removed it and it does not work :(

Comment: What version of jQuery are you loading?

Comment: @j08691 I am using jQuery 3.6.0